# how to reference s3 bucket in bucket policy without hardcoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a number of buckets in s3 that I want to add a specific statement to in the bucket policy. In many docs/example I see the resource section as follows:

```
"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
]
```

However, it is obviously tedious to change the bucket names every time I copy paste the statement for each different bucket. Is there a way I can reference the bucket in a 'dynamic' way, as well as the resources within the bucket, without hardcoding the bucket name, so that I can simply copy+paste the whole statement each time without editing the resources?

Comment: No, sadly there is no such way.